# FPU first command execution

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, fpu, x87

I ve this code, there we have a distance (D) and an angle (A), the functions must returns X, x=cosine(a)*d and Y,  y=sine(a)*d

```
.data    
n180 word 180
d word 60
a word 10
x word 0
y word 0

.code
    fild word ptr a
    fild word ptr n180
    fdiv
    fldpi
    fmul
    fsincos
    fild word ptr d
    fmul
    fistp word ptr x
    fwait
    fxch
    fild word ptr d
    fmul
    fistp word ptr y
```

at first time i run the program (using a=10 and d=60) i get X=59 e Y=-32768
here X is right, i get it before use `FXCH` but Y is wrong. if i run the program again then i get X=59 and Y=10
now it's ok

Why first time I run I get an error with `FXCH`?

Comment: @KenWhite i ve put in english

Comment: i ve tried use FINIT and FCLEX first... but no results... i ve got the answer at the second time i run the program

Comment: `fistp word ptr x` pops the stack... what do you expect the `fxch` to do ?

Comment: @ChrisHall I remove FXCH, it worked. fistp pops ST(0), is it right? i need sine and cosine, i forget fmul and fdiv it pops too... so i was using FXCH to get sine and cossine, but how FMUL pops, i don't need

Comment: I'm happy to hear it now works :-)  Yes, `ST(0)` is the current top-of-stack, so `fistp` pops that.  And yes, the no-operand `FADD`, `FDIV`, `FDIVR`, `FMUL`, `FSUB` and `FSUBR` all pop the right-hand argument `ST(0)`.  I note also that both `FADD` and `FADDP` (with no operands) are just shorthand for `FADDP ST(1), ST(0)` (Intel ordering) and that is *not* the same as `FADD ST(1), ST(0)`.  I note also that the Intel manual prefers the `FADDP` etc. mnemonics for the no-operand form.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness...

... the no-operand `FADD`, `FDIV`, `FDIVR`, `FMUL`, `FSUB` and `FSUBR` all pop the right-hand argument `ST(0)` (so the left-hand argument `ST(1)` is replaced by the result, and then the stack is popped and the result becomes `ST(0)`).

... so the `FXCH` is not required.

... indeed, without the `FXCH` your sequence of operations leaves the FPU register stack in the same state as it started in (assuming it does not overflow at any point), which is generally a Good Thing.

I note that both `FADD` and `FADDP` etc. (with no operands) are just shorthand for `FADDP ST(1), ST(0)` (Intel ordering) and that is *not* the same as `FADD ST(1), ST(0)`. I note also that the Intel manual prefers the `FADDP` etc. mnemonics for the no-operand form.